# Do you end pleads with an exclamation point?

Tags: punctuation

In my language an exclamation point is used at the end of a sentence if it is emotional, an order or if you are asking something of someone.

For example:
I am angry! - conveys a strong emotion
March forward! - gives an order
Please, write this!  - asks someone to do something

Does the rule for pleads (asking something of someone) hold true in the English language, as well?

Comment: This might be a philosophical issue more than a linguistic or typographical one, but to this US English speaker, "Please, write this!" is still an order, just like "March forward!"  The existence of "please" doesn't change that.   If you're really asking someone to do something, you would phrase it like "Could you please write this?"

Comment: @J Doe --  Do you mean "pleas", as in Stop! No!  Don't!  Or do you mean "please", as in Please, help me! (which would also be a plea).

Comment: @EllieK, I mean it as in the example I wrote - asking something of someone.

Comment: @J.Doe - Yes, but I think EllieK's point is that those are called *pleas*, not *pleads*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the exclamation mark could be used when you ask someone to do something *with urgency*. Simple humdrum requests are ordinarily punctuated with a period, not an exclamation point.

In other words, I'd write it like this:

> Please, write this.

However:

> Please, write this now! Our deadline is only thirty minutes away.

Comment: [Worth reading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).